# Перевернуть словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

У меня есть словарь:

```
alpha_ru = {'.-' : 'а', '-...' : 'б', '.--' : 'в',
        '--.' : 'г', '-..' : 'д', '.' : 'е',
        '...-' : 'ж', '--..' : 'з', '..' : 'и',
        '.---' : 'й', '-.-' : 'к', '.-..' : 'л',
        '--' : 'м', '-.' : 'н', '---' : 'о',
        '.--.' : 'п', '.-.' : 'р', '...' : 'с',
        '-' : 'т', '..-' : 'у', '..-.' : 'ф',
        '....' : 'х', '-.-.' : 'ц', '---.' : 'ч',
        '----' : 'ш', '--.-' : 'щ',
        '-.--' : 'ы', '-..-' : '(ь, ъ)', '..--..' : 'э',
        '..--' : 'ю', '.-.-' : 'я',
        '-----' : '0', '.----' : '1', '..---' : '2',
        '...--' : '3', '....-' : '4', '.....' : '5',
        '-....' : '6', '--...' : '7', '---..' : '8',
        '----.' : '9',
        '......' : '.', '--..--' : '!', '..--..' : '?',
        '---...' : ':', '-.-.-.' : ';', '-....-' : '-',
        '-..-.' : '/', '.-..-.' : '"', '-.--.' : '(',
        '-.--.-' : ')', '-...-' : '=', '.-.-.' : '+',
        '...-..-' : '$' , '.-.-..' : '¶', '..--.-' : '_',
        '.-.-.-' : ',', '' : ' '}
```

И мне нужно поменять местами ключ и значение. Но как? Смотрел на других сайтах - там все переворачивалось, но значение преобразовывалось в тип list, а мне нужно просто поменять местами ключ и значение.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот:

```
alpha_ru = {'.-' : 'а', '-...' : 'б', '.--' : 'в',
        '--.' : 'г', '-..' : 'д', '.' : 'е',
        '...-' : 'ж', '--..' : 'з', '..' : 'и',
        '.---' : 'й', '-.-' : 'к', '.-..' : 'л',
        '--' : 'м', '-.' : 'н', '---' : 'о',
        '.--.' : 'п', '.-.' : 'р', '...' : 'с',
        '-' : 'т', '..-' : 'у', '..-.' : 'ф',
        '....' : 'х', '-.-.' : 'ц', '---.' : 'ч',
        '----' : 'ш', '--.-' : 'щ',
        '-.--' : 'ы', '-..-' : '(ь, ъ)', '..--..' : 'э',
        '..--' : 'ю', '.-.-' : 'я',
        '-----' : '0', '.----' : '1', '..---' : '2',
        '...--' : '3', '....-' : '4', '.....' : '5',
        '-....' : '6', '--...' : '7', '---..' : '8',
        '----.' : '9',
        '......' : '.', '--..--' : '!', '..--..' : '?',
        '---...' : ':', '-.-.-.' : ';', '-....-' : '-',
        '-..-.' : '/', '.-..-.' : '"', '-.--.' : '(',
        '-.--.-' : ')', '-...-' : '=', '.-.-.' : '+',
        '...-..-' : '$' , '.-.-..' : '¶', '..--.-' : '_',
        '.-.-.-' : ',', '' : ' '}

inverted_dict = {v: k for k, v in alpha_ru.items()}

print(inverted_dict)
```

Comment: Премного благодарен

Comment: @Scourde примите ответ с помощью галки слева от него, если он решил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
alpha_ru_inverted={}
for k, v in alpha_ru.items():  
   alpha_ru_inverted[v]=k
```

Этот код создаст массив в котором значения изменены так как требуется

Comment: Во-первых, не массив, а словарь. Во-вторых, есть более оптимальный способ с генераторным выражением (см другой ответ)